# Symfony sfWidgetFormInputFile deleted my file

Tags: symfony1, upload, image, overwrite

Sorry for the many questions but I'm new to Symfony.   I made a form and all it working well.  I a few fields for pictures (Picture1, Picture2, Picture3, etc).   I used te sfWidgetFormInputFile and all is working well with that as well.   It uploads the file where it needs to and it gives it a unique name.

The problem I'm having is that those fields are set in mySQL to have a default value of "no-pic.png" so that if the user doesn't upload a picture, it will still have something to show in the post.   But every time someone uploads a picture, it deletes my no-pic.png file and the posts without a picture show with a blank square.  I'm thinking it's because it's set to "delete previous image" before uploading the new one to reduce excess unused pictures on the server.

I'm wondering if there's a way to have it check to see if the value is "no-pic.png" before deleting it from the folder.  In case it helps, this is the code I'm using in the form.class file.

```
      $this->widgetSchema['picture1'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array('label' => 'Pictures', ));
  $this->validatorSchema['picture1'] = new sfValidatorFile(array('required' => false, 'path' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/car', 'mime_types' => 'web_images', ));
  $this->widgetSchema['picture1'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
    'label' => 'Pictures',
    'file_src' => '/uploads/car/'.$this->getObject()->getPicture1(),
    'is_image' => true,
    'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew(),
    'template' => '<div>%file%<br />%input%<br />%delete%%delete_label%</div>',
    ));
  $this->validatorSchema['picture_delete'] = new sfValidatorPass();
```

Comment: You don't need the first line if you are allow them to edit the image upload. symfony will take care of the uploading and deleting for you but for some reason it doesn't let you delete and upload a new file at the same time (at least from my experience).

Comment: Cool.   I took out the first line and it still works but I need to be able to control the deletes myself.   I just added a post, uploaded an image, and the no-pic.png is gone.   I even tried making it read only.   It still deletes it.

Comment: Oh ok. I understand better what you want to do. Probably easiest way to prevent that is to bind the form in your controller, check to see if it's a delete and the picture is not no-pic.png. If both conditions are false then grab the object and update it. bindAndSave is good for if you wanted it to automatically take care of the delete and save for you but can't really do custom logic like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference here is the code I used.

```
$this->setWidget('logo_image', new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
  'file_src'  => 'uploads/logos/'.$this->getObject()->getFilename(),
  'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew()
)));

$validatorOptions = array(
  'max_size'           => 1024*1024*10,
  'path'               => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/logos',
  'mime_type_guessers' => array(),
  'required'           => false
);

if ($this->isNew())
{
  $validatorOptions['required'] = true;
}

$this->setValidator('logo_image', new sfValidatorFile($validatorOptions));
$this->setValidator('logo_image_delete', new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.  I had the page check to see if it was set to no-pic.png and then it displays a no-pic.png in another location.   That way when it goes to upload a picture, it won't delete it.   :)   Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Cool deal. I found the code I used and posted it for reference. It's simpler though and symfony does all of the work